# How to add a dropdown menu to a button in HTML/CSS using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I add a dropdown to a button in my HTML code . I have used the following code to generate a button and attached a dropdown to it , but it does not work .

The menu button is generated and it even highlights when clicked , but it does not display the dropdown , when clicked .

```css
.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  height: 120px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

body {
  background-color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron container"><strong>FEEDBACK</strong></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why use button if you can use select and option tag

Comment: I know I can do that , but this method should work as well . Infact the drop down code snippet is directly referenced from their documentation .    http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the `jQuery` library and `bootstrap.js` for this.

And why are you using `container` class inside your `col` classes...its not good practice.

> Read This: **[Bootstrap Grid Structure](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  height: 120px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

body {
  background-color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron container"><strong>FEEDBACK</strong></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you . It worked ! Also , I am very new to web development . I am just trying to make things work for now